# Random "not accessible" "you might not have permission to use this network resource"

Tags: windows-7, network-attached-storage

Win7-64 client computers connecting to a NAS share randomly get denied access. This appears as a dialog box appears saying "\\myServer\MyShare02 not accessible...you might not have permission to use this network resource..." or a dialog repeatedly asking for a password. A re-boot fixes the problem.

While the problem exists, other shares, say \\myServer\MyShare01, ARE accessible and other computers CAN access the shares denying access. So the problem seems to be on the client side.

Connecting using the IP address instead of the server name will work too.

When the problem appears, the network seems to be ok e.g. the affected computers can access other shares on the affected server and can ping etc. 'net use' doesn't show any lingering connections. Also Other computers can access the affected shares.

The NAS server is a NetGear ReadyNas Pro. The problem might be on the NAS side such as a resource limitation but since only 2 Win7-64 PCs seem to be affected the most, the problem could be on the PC side - I'm not sure yet.

I of course searched for solutions and found several tips addressing initial connection problems (use correct workgroup name, use IP address instead of server name, remove security restrictions etc) but none of those remedies address the random nature of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens, the event log usually doesn't show anything useful.

When the problem appears, using 'net use' (net use \myServer\MyShare02 /user:myId password) will result in this message:

```
System error 1219 has occurred.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more
 than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the
 server or shared resource and try again.
```

'net use' doesn't show any existing connections so 'net use * /delete' doesn't help.

When the problem appears, a reboot always works and connecting using the IP address works. So, 'net use \\MyShare02 /user:myId password' results in

```
The command completed successfully.
```

While this allows connection to the share, access using the server name still fails. This seems to imply that the problem is not on the server-side but rather on the client side. The IP-address work-around seems to work.

Comment: If this fixed it for you, you should accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything in the event log related to this? What about FSMGMT.MSC (while the issue exists)? It sounds like maybe a phantom share session is lingering after a loss in connectivity.

Comment: Cool. FSMGMT.MSC can be pointed to the NetGear NAS server and it shows share, session and file info. I'll try it the next time which will probably be within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

How does your client map to the NAS?  Meaning are you just directly mapping a drive to it, or is it done through DFS?  What control authentication to the device?  Once again, is this an AD integrated setup, or are you solely relying on the NAS to take care of the permissions?  Basically to better help troubleshoot this, at least I need to know more about your setup.

It would help if during the issue you could get some logs posted from the NAS device.  Also, try doing an NSlookup when its working and record the IP, and then try it again when its **not** working.  Perhaps something is messed up with DNS.